# How to install Android SDK on Linux after deleting earlier version? (2017 Martch)

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-sdk-2.3

In the past I could download and install Android SDK separately. I cannot find it any more on Google's Developer site, only Android Studio, which supposedly contains the SDK too (?). When starting the Android Studio it looks for the SDK.

I installed the Ubuntu (I'm using 16.10 Yakkety Yak) repo's Android SDK, that didn't help much because it is in /usr/lib/android-sdk with root privileges and Android Studio disses it. Now I'm scratching my head how I going to scrape all of that off as soon as I find out where can I install an SDK from.

*I did check at least 2-3 Stack Overflow Questions on the topic, but all of them seems to be outdated, so please be very careful to mark this as a duplicate.*

---

I have to add that I had both the SDK and the Studio installed before on my system. That turns out to be crucial info.

Comment: Try out from tutorials that have xenial (16.04) as distro version. I installed my Android Studio [by following these steps](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html) **worth to mention that I installed it on Ubuntu 16.04** and now I have upgraded it to yakkety. Thats all I can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after wiping the .Android-Studio-2.x and .android directories form my home, Android Studio offered the installation of the SDK. So the cause was leftover of previous installs, I haven't mentioned that fully in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are the "command-line tools" at https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads what you're looking for?

Comment: the command line tools unfortunately just a portion of the SDK.

Comment: Yes, but "You can use the included sdkmanager to download other SDK packages."

Comment: The sdk manager complains to me lately that it doesn't have a stand-alone UI any more, just the Android Studio integration one. It can install packages, but I don't know from the top of my head which ones I need from scratch. I had a lot in the stand-alone UI, the Android Studio shows much less.

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#linux-bundle and download the zip file. Extract it into your home directory(*or anywhere inside your home directory*).

Move into that extracted files directory, open up bin folder. You'll see a file[script] named studio.sh. Run that and Android will automatically start downloading the SDK.

Alternatively:

Set your `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable to /usr/lib/android-sdk:

`vim /home/user/.profile`

Add

`export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk"`

Comment: Yes. I didn't specify in detail that I had version of the Studio before on my system. But you are right.

Comment: You didn't have to wipe everything. You simply needed to point android studio to the correct sdk path

Comment: I wiped the SDK, I have technical troubles with developing a Wear app.